# how can I initialize a vector of lists in C++?

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, stdvector

I want to initialize a `vector` of `list<int>` . I used `fill` function, but my compiler shows error. Please help me in this direction.

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> neighbors(NRecords);
std::fill(neighbors.begin,neighbors.end,&std::vector<int>(NNeighbors)); // ERROR
```

> ERROR: Error 2 error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::begin': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::begin' to create a pointer to member   ...

Answer (score 5):

From what I can deduce from the code, it seems you simply want this:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> neighbors(NRecords, std::list<int>(NNeighbors));
```

This uses [a constructor (#2 in link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that is similar to the following:

```
vector(size_type count, value_type value);
```

In the above call, `NRecords` is the number of elements the vector will contain and the second argument, a list that is initialized the same way (it starts with `NNeighbors` as its size) is used for the value of each of the vector's elements. This saves having to create the vector with the size and then fill it separately.

For completeness, you have a couple things wrong with your `std::fill` call:

- First off, `begin` and `end` are functions, so you need parentheses (`begin()`).
- Secondly, you're filling it with `std::vector`s when you specified earlier that it contains `std::list`s.
- Next, you're passing a pointer to the value instead of the value itself.
- Finally, you're taking the address of a temporary container you create on the fly in there, which is not allowed. You shouldn't be taking the address in the first place, though.

Corrected, it can be written as:

```
std::fill(neighbours.begin(), neighbours.end(), std::list<int>(NNeighbors));
```

Comment: Thank you really. Would you please let me a reference about the syntax. It seems really complex for me from the prototype of the function to understand it.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi, I updated the answer to explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

`neighbors.begin` should be `neighbors.begin()`

`neighbors.end` should be `neighbors.end()`

```
std::fill(neighbors.begin(),neighbors.end(),std::list<int>(NNeighbors));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector`'s constructor as per Chris's post

or else:

`std::fill(neighbors.begin(),neighbors.end(),std::list<int>(NNeighbors));`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly you simply want to declare a vector of lists.
I have gotten this to work in my main file but can not figure out
how to do so as a private member of a class.....

```
vector< list < string >> hashTable(1373);
```